# How can I rename the file I'm editing?

Tags: save, file-operations

Is it possible to rename the file I'm editing from within Vim? Currently what I do is exit Vim, rename the file and open from Vim again.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205286/renaming-the-current-file-in-vim

Comment: I am interested to do this in neovim

Comment: @MigueldeVal-Borro Just use [vim-eunuch](https://github.com/tpope/vim-eunuch). It also works for Neovim.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You could save the file under a different name using `:w newname`. But this operation won't remove the old file and the 'old' file stays in your buffer, so any changes will be applied to your 'old' file.

`:saveas` saves your new file and opens it in a new buffer. But it doesn't delete the old file.

I use [tpope/vim-eunuch](https://github.com/tpope/vim-eunuch) to `:Move` files.

> :Move: Rename a buffer and the file on disk simultaneously.

Comment: One downside of `:w` or `:saveas` is that it will lose the execute permission if you were editing a script. `netrw` Rename will keep the permissions.

Comment: Is `:Move` effetively the same as `:!mv {src} {dest}`, and then running `:e {src}`, where {src} is the name of the old buffer which consequently is destroyed seeing as you will get `E211: File {src} no longer available, and where {dest} is the name of the new buffer?

Comment: If most of the time all you do is rename files, then sure, VS Code perhaps does a better job. But if most of the time you edit code or text, then you might want to check the VIM motions, commands, and other features that beat VS Code and potentially all other editors out there hands down. Watch this video to get an idea of what I mean: https://youtu.be/X6AR2RMB5tE

Answer (score 17):

You could drop to *Netrw* and rename the file there.

If the file you're editing is in the current directory, then do:

```
:edit .
```

Navigate to the file, press <kbd>R</kbd>, and change the name.
Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to edit the file.

There's a caveat though: the original buffer remains in the list of buffers.
If you switch to it, it's empty.

If the file you're editing is in a different directory, you can change to the file's directory with:

```
:cd %:p:h
```

If you don't want to change the directory for the entire Vim session but only for the current buffer, then you can do instead:

```
:lcd %:p:h
```

Comment: Typing straight `:edit %:p:h` also seems to work.

Comment: `:E` will also open netrw

Comment: I use `:ex<tab>` which expands to `:Explore`.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 12):

I've been using the [Rename2 plugin](https://github.com/vim-scripts/Rename2) for this for years. It renames both the current buffer, and the file on disk:

```
:Rename {newname}
```

EDIT: I found this a `.vimrc` file on [github](https://github.com/garybernhardt/dotfiles/blob/master/.vimrc):

```
function! RenameFile()
    let old_name = expand('%')
    let new_name = input('New file name: ', expand('%'), 'file')
    if new_name != '' && new_name != old_name
        exec ':saveas ' . new_name
        exec ':silent !rm ' . old_name
        redraw!
    endif
endfunction
map <leader>n :call RenameFile()<cr>
```

Comment: If those who use this snippet need to delete the buffer with the old file, you can add `exec ':bd ' . old_file` after the `silent !rm …` line

Answer (score 5):

The best way is to use `:Move`, as OrangTux said. For completeness, you can also perform terminal commands in vi editors using a bang (`!`) in command mode.

```
:!mv {current_file} {new_name}
:e {new_name}
```

However, this method doesn't remove the old buffer from your buffer list.

Answer (score 5):

An easy way to rename file in Vim is `:Explore` command. Navigate to file which you want to rename type `R` command than rename file

Answer (score 0):

You can just shell command from vim. A bit dirty since the old buffer is still in place but with NerdTree plugin it's good enough for me:

```
!mv <current path> <new path>
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!