# How can I copy the current file and start editing the copy instead of the current file?

Tags: save, multiple-files, file-operations

Say I'm editing file `foo`. I want to copy/write what I have in the buffer to `bar` and change the buffer to be editing `bar` instead of `foo`. I can achieve this with:

```
:w bar
:e bar
```

But that has a few problems

1. If `bar` is actually `/usr/local/share/long/path/to/bar`, I really don't want to type that in twice, even with tab completion.
2. It reloads the file, potentially messing with the settings/folds/etc. I had for that buffer.
3. The working directory is left the same.

1 is the biggest problem I'd like a solution to address; 2 would be really helpful, 3 is more of a "nice to have."

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: I think this is what you want? [How can I rename the file I'm editing?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/305/how-can-i-rename-the-file-im-editing?s=1|0.8744). It doesn't do anything about the working directory, but you can fix that with `:cd %:p:h`.

Comment: You can define a function yourself that does this, called e.g. `:we` -- is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 14):

Here's a relatively simple solution:

```
:saveas bar
```

This solves problems #1 and #2. It doesn't address problem #3, however.

Note that this still leaves the old file open in another buffer. For example, `:w foo<cr>:saveas bar<cr>:ls<cr>` will list two buffers, `foo` and `bar`.

Comment: Beat me by twelve seconds!

Comment: Indeed, saveas is what I was looking for. I don't suppose there's an option to have it open in a new window, is there?

Comment: @Kevin By "window," do you mean split or tab?

Comment: Split, preferably vertical (or an option for both)

Comment: @Kevin Not that I'm aware of, but you could always use, for example, `<C-w><C-s>:saveas bar<cr>`. (This could be all in one ex command if you want to make a mapping or something: `:wincmd s|saveas bar`.)

Comment: @Kevin `:vs` (with no argument) will split the window, having the same file in both buffers. You can then choose one of the buffers and use `:saveas bar.txt`, it will leave the 2nd buffer intact.

Answer (score 4):

If you are working on a file that is not in the current working directory, and you want to save it under a new name in that directory, you can use the following:

```
execute 'saveas' expand('%:h') . "/new-file-name"
```

The `execute` command allows you to use an argument to `saveas` that is not a literal string. `expand('%:h')` gets the relative path of the current file. The rest of the statement concatenates the new file name.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: Binding this with a `map` and it works like a charm!

Comment: who not just `:sav %:h/new-file-name`?

Comment: I would like to know the difference btw these two, too!

Answer (score 2):

Write the file as usual: `:w bar` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>^</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd>) to alternate the file.

For splits (`:ba`/`:vert ba`), check: [How to convert all windows into horizontal, vertical or tab splits?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/758/467)

See: `:help ctrl-6`.

Comment: Definitely helps avoiding typing out the name twice, but does reopen like `:e`.